# What does each character specialize in?

Tags: bravely-default

I know that whatever job you have does not affect stat growth, so clearly each character has some specific base stat distribution and innate strengths and weaknesses. So, which characters do best in which classes? For example, does Tiz do better as an AGI-focused class compared to, say, Edea or Agnes? Or do the characters all have the same stat distribution and growth and Black Mage Agnes would do the same damage as Black Mage Ringabel given all things equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check the base stats of each character under the "status" menu, in "tactics."

I'm currently playing through at level 13, so my stats may differ from yours; however, the base values for my current party are as follows:

Tiz:
Str 16
Vit 16
Int 15
Mnd 16
Dex 16
Agi 14

Agnes:
Str 14
Vit 14
Int 17
Mnd 17
Dex 14
Agi 13

Ringabel:
Str 15
vit 15
Int 16
Mnd 14
Dex 17
Agi 17

Edea:
Str 17
Vit 17
Int 14
Mnd 15
Dex 15
Agi 14

So as you can see, Edea is suited to be a fighter-type; Ringabel, to be a faster type, a la thief or ninja; Agnes is best as a mage; and Tiz is an all-rounder with slight leanings toward Mind-type or Strength-type jobs.

Edit to add:
However, the other poster IS indeed correct that the difference is pretty small, and mostly insignificant. As a minmaxer, though, the difference between 17 base Dex and 14 base Dex is pretty huge early in the game.

Answer (score 6):

I can give you the base stats at level 99 and I'll let you make the final decisions on their classes.
As a guideline, Tiz is more balanced, Agnès is more Magic oriented, Ringabel more speed oriented, and Edea is more strength oriented.

```
          |  HP  |  MP | STR | VIT | INT | MND | DEX | AGI
----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------
Tiz       | 6777 | 542 |  65 |  65 |  64 |  65 |  65 |  65
Agnès     | 6750 | 555 |  63 |  63 |  66 |  66 |  63 |  64
Ringabel  | 6765 | 551 |  64 |  64 |  65 |  63 |  66 |  66
Edea      | 6753 | 551 |  66 |  66 |  63 |  63 |  64 |  63
```

Answer (score 4):

Everyone starts out as a Freelancer, and from what I've noticed of the stats, everyone seems fairly suited to all of the jobs. Taking a job automatically adjusts all the stats based on the job modifier, *making* them suitable for job. It would seriously upset the balance of the game if any of the party members were unsuitable for a job.

And with the difference being only a few points between characters, it won't matter in the long run.

Comment: So, given equal equipment, levels, and abilities Black Mage Agnes would have the same amount of M. Atk and INT as Black Mage Ringabel?

Comment: @Yuki more or less, the "wobble" or difference in the stats between equal characters is only a few points from what I recall reading.